# How to make Windows USB on Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, windows, windows-7, media, unetbootin

I have tried just dropping the files but its not booting so how can I put the iso on the usb and its bootable to where it works. UNETBOOTIN DID NOT WORK FOR ME.

Answer (score 2):

To make a bootable Windows USB disk on Ubuntu, I would recommend using WoeUSB. To install it, use the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt update
sudo apt install woeusb
```

Format your USB drive as NTFS (open your files, secondary-click on the USB drive, click "Format", and select "Type" as "NTFS").

Open WoeUSB, select the Windows ISO file, and select the USB drive. Click "Install". This might take a while. When it's finished, you should see "Installation succeeded!".

You now have a bootable Windows USB drive.

Comment: I got an error https://imgur.com/a/24TrdKB when trying